# Show progressbar using jquery ui while uploading multiple file in phonegap android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, file-upload, cordova

I am uploading some images to the server in my android app.What i want is while uploading i want to show progress bar instead of loading image so the user can understand the amount of images upload. I creating this app using jquery and jquery-ui 1.10.2 only. I treid the example shown in the jQuery ui site for custom progress bar but i am not able to use it correctly the issue is while uploading it shows progress bar only till 50% but all the images are getting uploaded here the code that i had use for progress bar and uploading image:

```
    var file_uri = ['file:///mnt/sdcard/TEST_demo/TEST_710_1113.jpg',
                'file:///mnt/sdcard/TEST_demo/TEST_710_1114.jpg',
                'file:///mnt/sdcard/TEST_demo/TEST_710_1115.jpg',
                'file:///mnt/sdcard/TEST_demo/TEST_710_1116.jpg'];
function upload_image()
{
for(var i =0;i<file_uri.length;i++)
{
    var imageURI = file_uri[i];
    server = urlserver+'upload.php';
    if (server) {

        var option = new FileUploadOptions();
            option.fileKey="file";
            option.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            option.mimeType="image/jpeg/doc/docx/pdf/txt";
            option.chunkedMode = false;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();

        ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                var loaded = device.platform == "Android" ? (progressEvent.loaded / 2) : progressEvent.loaded;
                var perc =    Math.round( (loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100 );
                var progressbar = $("#progressbar"), progressLabel = $(".progress-label");
                progressbar.progressbar({
                    value : false,
                    change : function() {
                        console.log('in change function:');
                        progressLabel.text(progressbar.progressbar("value") + "%");
                    },
                    complete : function() {
                        progressLabel.text("Complete!");
                    }
                });
                function progress() {
                    console.log('in progress function');
//                      var val = progressbar.progressbar("value") || 0;
                    progressbar.progressbar("value", perc);
                    if (perc < 99) {
                        setTimeout(progress, 100);
                    }
                }
                setTimeout(progress, 1000);
            }
        }
        ft.upload(imageURI, server, function(r) {   
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload successful: "+r.bytesSent+" bytes uploaded.";              
        }, function(error) {
            document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Upload failed: Code = "+error.code;               
        }, option);
    }
}    }
```

Comment: i know its quite old question but do you have the complete code. As i am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `/2`, that is why your progress finishes at 50%:

```
var loaded = device.platform == "Android" ? (progressEvent.loaded / 2) : progressEvent.loaded;
```

**New code:**

```
var loaded = progressEvent.loaded;
```